# Visualise output from David Blei's HDP topic model algorithm in R

Tags: r, topic-models

I've been experimenting with [David Blei's C++ HDP implementation](https://github.com/blei-lab/hdp) but am struggling to print the topics using the R.

The package includes an R script for printing the identified topics, `print.topics.r` and the documentation that comes with the package provides some instructions for its use as follows:

> A R script (print.topics.R) is included to print topics. Make sure it is executable. (chmod +x print.topics.R) For example,
>
> print.topics.R mode-topics.dat vocab.dat topics.dat 10

I've made the script executable, but I'm struggling to get it to work. I have a range of files in the output directory from running the algorithm, but don't seem to be able to identify the right combination of files to pass in as arguments to the script.

The files I'm working with are:

test-mode-topics.dat
test-mode-word-assignments.dat

I don't have a vocab.dat file, but I do have a vocab.txt file (which I also renamed to vocab.dat to no avail).

I've tried running the following command:

`./print.topics.r test-mode-word-assignments.dat vocab.dat test-mode-topics.dat`

This returns the following error:

> Error in sum(prob) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
>   Calls: print.topics
>   Execution halted

Has anyone figured out the right way to structure the command with the available files?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: The problem can be replicated by running the code in the linked git repo.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of wrangling, I managed to get the following command to play ball:

```
./print.topics.r /path/to/mode-topics.dat/ /path/to/vocab.dat topics.dat 4
```

The first arg passes in the mode-topics.dat file generated by HDP.

The second arg passes in the file containing a list of the words in the corpus

The third argument passes in the number of terms per topic (the default is 5)